# jQWidgets Splitter Widget causing loss focus or event consumption

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm using a [splitter from jQWidegts](http://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/#demos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm) and am experiencing some strange behaviour when the splitter is enabled. When it's disabled the strange behaviour stops. I have created a [JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qKdgL/) - it's as simple as I could get it.

To recreate the problem:

1. Load the JSFiddle and before doing anything, mouseover the Submit
   button or the 'String' tab.
2. The submit button should change to a red `color` and the 'String'
   tab also changes style.
3. Next, click in some white space, for example, below the Submit
   button or 'String' tab.
4. Now mouseover the button or tab - the style no longer changes for
   either.
5. If you click again in some white-space, then mouseover, the style
   does change.

This is **not** toggle-like behaviour since clicking a third time will not prevent styling on mouseover. It only occurs the first time.

If I comment out the line that sets up the splitter:

```
$('#splitter').jqxSplitter(splitterConf);
```

then the problem goes away. Any HTML elements outside of the `splitter` div, not not experience this problem.

My only thought is that an event is being consumed by the splitter and not propagated. However the `splitter` div doesn't have any events attached to it, at least they don't show in Chrome's JavaScript debugger.

I have noticed that when white-space is clicked (to trigger the problem), an extra `div` element is being appended to the DOM:

`<div style="width: 1680px; height: 275px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; "></div>`

This element is being appended by `jqxsplitter.js` in the following code:

```
initOverlay: function(c) {
            var b = this;
            if (b.overlay && c == undefined) {
                b.overlay.remove()
            } else {
                b.overlay = a("<div></div>");
                b.overlay.width(b.host.width());
                b.overlay.height(b.host.height());
                b.overlay.css("position", "absolute");
                b.overlay.appendTo(a(document.body));
                var d = b.host.offset();
                b.overlay.css("left", d.left);
                b.overlay.css("top", d.top)
            }
```

From the callstack I see it's called from _stopDrag, so it seems to be some way of preventing dragging:

```
_stopDrag: function(b) {
        if (b._capturedElement) {
            b._performAreaResize();
            b._capturedElement.remove()
        }
        b._capturedElement = null;
        b._initOverlay()
```

But I don't know why this is occurring or why it's causing a problem. Ideally someone knows what the problem is, but failing that, some tips on how to debug / move towards a solution would be good.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com) Team

> This is a known issue and will be resolved in the next release.

Src: http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/splitter-widget-causing-loss-focus-or-event-consumption